# Is it possible to set not module *.js file as a dependency using require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

We do not use require.js for implementing modules on js source, but I want to use it for tests. And there is a problem: I couldn't implement raw *.js file as a dependency for other modules. Is it possible?

I mean: load some *.js file and modules after it (to test it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How `define` works

I use require.js for both implementation and tests. You can load any JavaScript file as a dependency *before* the execution of the module function using `define`.

```
define(["test/myTest.js", "test/anotherTest.js"], function(test1, test2) {
  // perform your tests
});
```

## How to use `requirejs` with asyncTests

You can also load code *after* the dependencies are loaded *inside* the module function using `require`. I use it with *QUnit*. Here is an example from my code.

First, make sure QUnit test runner is stopped by default (this will be similar with other test frameworks). This way, you can define when tests are going to run (that is after you loaded the relevant code).

`QUnit.config.autostart = false`

Second, you define your test as a module. The module loads the dependencies, then defines the tests, then loads the code to be tested. This will only be necessary when the code is self-executing and can not be load beforehand (in which case you could just go with define and be done with it). Here is my example using the `Chaplin` library (written in CoffeeScript).

```
define(['chaplin'], function(chaplin) {
  asyncTest("publish startup complete event", function() {
    chaplin.mediator.subscribe("startup~complete", function() {
      ok(true, "startup~complete event fired");
    });
    return requirejs(['modules/startup/startup'], function() {
      start();
    });
  });
});
```

The important part is the last `requirejs` call. It loads the code to be tested after the tests are defined.

## dynamically loading dependencies

EDIT: Responding to comment
Assuming there exists a module called `config` that contains the configuration data. I am also assuming a certain format, so if your format is different you may make some minor changes. The principles holds true though.

```
define(["config"], function(config) {
  // assuming config.modules is an array of all development modules,
  // config.devPath is the base bath to development modules,
  requirejs(
    config.modules.map(function(module){
      return config.devPath + module
    })
  , function() {
    // all modules loaded, now go on
    // however, no reference to modules left, so need to work with `arguments` array
  });
});
```

However, you should know you lose the reference to your modules in the callback function.

Comment: Yep, cool, and what could I do if `config` module contains host from which i'm going to load file, as a dependency?

Comment: Please confirm: You have a module called `config` that contains the host addresses (url) of the other modules? So in a sense, you are trying to dynamically load your dependencies?

Comment: Yep, different hosts: production/test etc.

Comment: I fixed problem with config file. Files are on different servers (http://myserver.com/). And not all, only some. But now there is a problem with loading files... My modules loads in order they should, but file dependencies - not, if I want to load journal.js after basic.js (cuz journal uses basic)... and I have something: 
`journal.js`,  
`basic.js`, 
`files/basic` (my module that depends on journal.js), 
`files/journal` (my module that depends on both),

you can see that order of my sources is incorrect, but modules - ok.. :(

Comment: I think it's time to submit a new question with you concrete issue that you have now.